# Fabric - Running sed on a local file

Tags: python, sed, fabric

I am trying to run sed on a file locally, here is my code:

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.files import sed
import os.path

def init(project, repository=None): 
    repository = project if not repository else repository
    folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), repository)

    local('cp -R bin/* %s' % folder)

    with lcd(folder):
        sed('wsgi.py', '{PROJECTNAME}', project)
```

It is then prompting me to specify a host. Is there any way I can run sed locally like this? I also tried:

```
local("sed -i \'s/{PROJECTNAME}/%s/\' wsgi.py" % project)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> sed: -i may not be used with stdin

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the sed contrib API, but fabric's docs say about the local function:

`local is simply a convenience wrapper around the use of the builtin Python subprocess module with shell=True activated. If you need to do anything special, consider using the subprocess module directly.`

So I suggest you just call `subprocess.call()` with `shell=False`, that should probably fix the error with `sed -i`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by using the following:

```
local("sed -i \'\' -e\'s/{PROJECTNAME}/%s/\' wsgi.py" % project)
```

I am not sure why this works with the extra \'\' and what the implications are exactly, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the reason that this fixes your issue is that you're using Mac OS X (or another BSD).

The BSD version of `sed` requires the `-i` argument to have a value. That value should be the file extension that `sed` will use to create a backup, in case an error occurs during `sed` processing and the file needs to be rolled back to its original contents. The value can also be an empty string (`''`), indicating to `sed` that no backup file should be created.

GNU's version of `sed` is smarter, and knows that, if no value is passed, then no backup should be created. It does not need the empty string.